# Nginx, Let's encrypt cause error redirect http to https partially

Tags: centos, nginx, http, https, letsencrypt

I am using CentOS 7, Let's encrypt (want to clear all thing related 002.bkit.vn),  Nginx.

I try to install Let's encrypt for 002.bkit.vn , then I remove it, some things still exist, but I don't know how to clear it.

Then, This is my website https://002.bkit.vn/

If I allow Google Chrome load unsafe script, it will display quite good.

How to remove redirecting http to https?